# SQL - count instances of item matching TEXT for each user

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a dataset formatted like this:

```
ID  URL
1   google.com/trees
1   Wikipedia.com
1   Wikipedia.com/trees
2   Hello.com
2   Yahoo.com
3   Wikipedia.com
3   Google.com
3   MSN.com
```

I want to create a table (an actual data set, not just a table in the output window) formatted like this, which essentially sums up visitation to each of those domains.

```
ID  Wikipedia.com   Google.com  Hello.com   Yahoo.com   MSN.com
1   2               1           0           0           0
2   0               0           1           1           0
3   1               1           0           0           1
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you locking in the sites or are those dynamic too?

Comment: TSQL.

Each row is a user with a URL visit. I need to tabulate totals for each domain (meaning wikipedia.com/trees and wikipedia.com/sql) would be treated the same

Comment: Please don't close this question. I think I provided a good answer. Question also got at least 3 upvotes

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: I disagree. The OP did not seem to make any effort to solve this on his own which is a common guideline on SO!

Answer (score 1):

This works for mssql version 2008

```
declare @yourtable table(id int, URL varchar(20))
insert @yourtable values(1, 'google.com/trees')
insert @yourtable values(1, 'Wikipedia.com')
insert @yourtable values(1, 'Wikipedia.com/trees')
insert @yourtable values(2, 'Hello.com')

declare @shorturltable table(URL varchar(20))
insert @shorturltable values
('Wikipedia.com'),('Google.com'),('Hello.com'),('Yahoo.com'),('MSN.com')


;with t as(
 SELECT 1 a, y.id, su.URL 
 FROM @yourtable y
 JOIN @shorturltable su
 ON y.URL like '%' + su.URL + '%'
) 
SELECT id, [Wikipedia.com],[Google.com],[Hello.com],[Yahoo.com],[MSN.com]
FROM t
PIVOT (count(a) FOR [URL] IN ([Wikipedia.com],[Google.com],[Hello.com],[Yahoo.com],[MSN.com])) AS pvt
```

[Link to test](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/144507/1)